# non(Meager) in Random times Random extension

Tags: set-theory

Suppose the least size of a non meager set of reals is $\kappa$. Is it still $\kappa$ after forcing with Random $\times$ Random?

Comment: In the random real extension, non(Meager) is preserved.

Comment: Isn't Random$\times$Random, the same as two step iteration of Random. If so, then just use your above comment two times!

Comment: @MohammadGolshani No. Random$\times$Random adds Cohen reals, for example. A two step iteration of Random is isomorphic to a single step.

Comment: I have a proof (communicated by Shelah) that non(Meager) is preserved in $V^P$ where $P$ is a finite support iteration of random forcing of length $\omega$ (so a Cohen is added in the limit). Perhaps $P$ and Random X Random are forcing equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious to hear the set-theoretic answer. In the meantime it's interesting to note that in the computability-theoretic setting the answer seems to be "no".

There the analogue would be:
Suppose $A$ does not compute any [weakly meager engulfing](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2839v2.pdf) (w.m.e.) set, and $B$ is Schnorr (say) random over $A$. Then does $B\oplus A$ still not compute a w.m.e. set?
But in that setting, w.m.e. is the same up to Turing degree as high-or-DNR (by link above), and each Schnorr random set does have that property by a result of Nies, Stephan, and Terwijn (see "Ref 24" in the paper linked above).